# Notation clarification: What is the meaning of $\frac{\omega}{\mathrm{d}t}$?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, geodesic

Here is a homework question:
Let $M$ be a $C^\infty$ differentiable manifold with the affine connection $\nabla$, $\{e_i\}$ be a local frame, $\{\omega^i\}$ be its dual frame, $\{\omega_{j}^i\}$ be the connection $1$-forms.

(1) Show that the geodesic equation is
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\left(\frac{\omega_k}{\mathrm{d}t}\right)+\frac{\omega_i}{\mathrm{d}t}\frac{\omega_{i}^k}{\mathrm{d} t}=0$$

I am confused with the notations $\frac{\omega}{\mathrm{d}t}$ where $\omega$ is an 1-form. Any explanation of references are welcomed. THANKS!

Comment: Our of context, this makes no sense. You should include a reference and a link if you have one. It is possible that you are also given a curve $c(t)$ and you are taking pull-backs of forms via this curve. It is also possible that there is a typo and the author means the covariant derivative along $c(t)$...

Comment: When you pull the connnection 1-forms back along a curve $\gamma$ you’ll get some function of $t$ times $dt$. This ‘ratio’ refers to that function.

Comment: See [this PhySE answer of mine](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/769581/203278), especially the second section about kinematics. but yea tldr is you just pullback a $1$-form along a curve

Comment: @peek-a-boo Thank you! I got it.